# Load nested object on an array dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have a `json` data in this format and I would like to load data in an array which is an object, without hard coding the object keys. I would like to get items and labels in each category and each category has it name for object key. At the moment I get the data by
 `...myData.labels.name;` or `...items.name;` which is not effective because
the name changes depending on the category.

```
  [
  [
    {
      "key": "mykey",
      "category": "myCategoryKey",
      "category_label": "myCategoryLabel",
      "field": "filter",
      "items": {
        "name": [
          "item1",
          "item2"
        ]
      },
      "labels": {
        "name": [
          "Item1",
          "Item2"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "mykey2",
      "category": "myCategoryKey2",
      "category_label": "myCategoryLabel2",
      "field": "filter",
      "items": {
        "name2": [
          "item1",
          "item2"
        ]
      },
      "labels": {
        "name3": [
          "Item1",
          "Item2"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Use `Object.keys(myData.labels);` to get all items present in labels and then use `myData.labels[key]` to get that following value.

Comment: please add a wanted result as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.keys()` to get Keys for items present if values change dynamically.

And then use the keys to get corresponding values.

```js
var data = {
            "key": "mykey2",
            "category": "myCategoryKey2",
            "category_label": "myCategoryLabel2",
            "field": "filter",
            "items": {
                "name2": [
                    "item1",
                    "item2"
                ]
            },
            "labels": {
                "name3": [
                    "Item1",
                    "Item2"
                ]
 } }
 
 var labelsPresent = Object.keys(data.labels);
 
 console.log(labelsPresent);
 
 var labelValues= labelsPresent[0];
 console.log(data.labels[labelValues]);
```